# Creating a full screen video overlay without Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to jQuery but really liking what it can do, I am making good progress with it but I am unable to achieving to open a `div` when I press play.
I do not want to use Bootstrap modal for this project. What I want is to open the video as a full width and height of viewport width and height.
Currently it is not playing, here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/vgmaxK) and my code is below.

As an example I want to achieve something like [this](http://www.joe-san.com/), when play is pressed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".glyphicon-play-circle").click(function(){
        $(".movie").css("display","block")
    })
})
```

CSS

```
.movie{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:black;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a changes to your code. I disabled the fullscreen content because it's enough one video to make it full. No need extra video it make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".glyphicon-play-circle").click(function() {
        $(".movie").css("display", "block")
        $("#bgvid").toggleClass("is-not-active");
        $(".fullscreen").toggleClass("is-video-active");
        $(".fullscreen.is-video-active").prop("autoplay", true);
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.glyphicon {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px
}

nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.centered {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
}

.content {
    /*position: relative;*/
}

video {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: contain;
}


.movie {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}
.is-not-active { display: none;}
.fullscreen { display: none; }
.fullscreen.is-video-active {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
}

.is-video-active video {
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <section class="header container">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150" alt="">
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teach</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="centered">
                <h1 class="text-center">We Evolve with our students</h1>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
                    <a/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
            <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
            <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
                </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="fullscreen">
        <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline muted loop>
            <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
            <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4" style="display: none;">
        </video>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still trying to understand it, I want a video as a trailer and when you click on it, it runs the other movie as i had paid for two movies. Wouldn't it work?

Comment: @Nofel do you want to run the full screen div on the trailer click??

Comment: yes, by movie i mean the ad with sound, where as trailer is just few second and muted.

Comment: Always try to add a class with jQuery before you use the `.css()` method.

Comment: @YonasHailu Thanks it helped. But if i do <video autoplay> on the hidden video, it plays the sound without the video(as clicking the icon will play video). I want sound only if the video is playing and the video should play when .fullscreen , right now it plays when page loads and display when you clicked.

Comment: @YonasHailu i got the video autoplay removed from page , now when the fuillscreen loads, it is blank.How can i make the video play when the fullscreen loads.

Comment: @Nofel Let me check it please

Comment: @Nofel I have updated the code. What I did is I removed the autoplay attribute from the video & I added it when the fullscreen is active.

Comment: @YonasHailu i created a new thread. you may want to have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841065/video-wont-play-after-first-time-playing)

Comment: @YonasHailu How will i make [this](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/bgrLZV) code stop working after i click it while it is playing.

Comment: @Nofel sorry The link is broken? please send me complete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133985/discussion-between-nofel-and-yonas-hailu).